# Including a C# Interface in a IDL Library

Tags: c#, c++, com, idl, midl

I have an interface define in C#, for example:

```
[ComVisible(true), Guid("E37EBA3C-FB2E-4D4A-8A90-F6FAA99E85C9")]
public interface TestClass
{
    public void test_function();
}
```

I want to include this in a library define in IDL. I tried to achieve this by generating a .tlb from C# interface and include it with importlib. However, I do not see this interface in my library when I compile my idl file, but I see all of the other interfaces that I defined in this library through importing their idl files.

```
import "AnotherClass.idl"
library COMMONPROGRAMS{
    importLib(stdole32.tlb)
    importLib(stdole2.tlb)
    importLib(TestClass.tlb)

    interface TestClass;
    interface AnotherClass;
}
```

In summary, I want to know:

- Is it possible to include a C# interface in a IDL library?
- If so, how can I do this?

All answers are welcome. Thank you in advance for any answers submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import a TLB with `importlib` you don't see the interfaces in the current TLB as they are not a part of that TLB. Those interfaces are already defined in `TestClass` type library, so they can't have another definition in the `CommonPrograms` library.

If you want to define the interface elsewhere but make it a part of your TLB, you need to import it with `import TestClass.idl`. One way to generate the IDL from TLB is to open the TLB in OLE/COM Object Viewer and choose `File->Save As`, then edit it. I suppose that this is not what you want, as most likely you want to have this procedure automated.

However, with `importlib` you can still reference `TestClass` interface from CommonPrograms types, so this is usually not a big obstacle, but that obviously depends on your requirements.